# Enforce one common instance of static variables to all threads when running in the context of appDomain

Tags: c#, multithreading, static, native, appdomain

**Environment:**
.NET Program that contains multiple dlls/assemblies of managed + native code.
The first action performed by the program is to create an instance of a class (say classA) that is inherited from MarshalByRefObject, within a namespace (say namespaceA).

Actions done as part of classA constructor:

- Allocates new class (say classB). classB contains static variables.
- Create threads. The actual creation of the threads is done in the context of the native code by calling the ‘WinBase’ ‘CreateThread’ function.

**Problem:**
When defining an instance of classA within the context of appDomain, classB static variables are not common to all threads.

The code used to load the programs dll and create instance of classA within appDomain:

```
System.AppDomain app_domain = System.AppDomain.CreateDomain("app domain");
object winfw_host = app_domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(@"C:\...\dll_name.dll", "namespaceA.classA");
```

**Note:**
When defining an instance of classA not in the context of appDomain, classB static variables are common to all threads.

**Question:**

I would have expected same behavior (AppDomain and non-AppDomain context), what is the reason for the difference?

Is it possible to enforce one common instance of static variables to all threads when running in the context of appDomain?

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a static variable is exactly the containing AppDomain. In order to recover this limitation, I would recommend to use some tricky way.

You select an AppDomain (let's say A).
AppDomain class exposes the following non-static methods.

```
GetData(String)
SetData(String, Object)
```

Try to store the value shared by all AppDomain by A.SetData("your Key", value), and retrieve value by A.GetData("your key")

You will need to also think of thread safe access when accessing the AppDomain A.

Comment: The second parameter of "SetData" method will need to be either value type or type inheriting MarshalByRefObject class.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft approved that it is an expected behaviour that when creating multile threads in appDomian context, static variable are not to be common for all thread (unlike non-appDomain, one static variable for all threads) and it’s how C++/CLI was implemented.
To achieve this kind of requirement it is suggestion is to create a delegate type to wrap managed method call so it could be passed to native code into the native threads, because delegates preserve that AppDomain information across native threads. Basically, you create the managed delegate, allocate a GCHandle for the delegate to reference it in your native C++ code, then call Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate on the GCHandle to get the native function pointer to the delegate. The last part requires a static cast of the IntPtr to your native function type. You can then pass that native function pointer you obtain across threads.